# multiprocessing counters and printing multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to figure out how to implement a print statement that will only print once in a function that has a pool of workers on it. So if they're is 2 threads running in the pool, I only want 1 thread to print it. I am trying to achieve this by using a counter, I have been messing around with the multiprocessing.Value that way it will increment right, but I removed it for now. Every time the counter hits 5 it will minus 5 from the counter and print something.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, Lock
from colorama import Fore
counter = 0
def check(line):
    counter+=1
    if counter == 5:
        counter-=5
        print(Fore.YELLOW + "Counter Reached 5")
    else:
        pass
    #my other code here that normally gets executed 
def main():
    #args.threads is taken from an argument given by the user before program starts
    pool = Pool(args.threads)
    pool.daemon = True
    results = pool.map(check, arrange)
```

Of course they're is more code, but this is what I need help with. When the counter reaches 5, I want only one thread to print something instead of all of the threads in the pool.

Comment: processes do not share state.

Comment: so I cant accomplish what im trying to do? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: You can, but you have to handle [sharing state](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) yourself. You've created two different *processes* which are not sharing memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example close to what you have above...

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, Lock

counter = Value('i',0)  # integer value starting at 0
lock = Lock()

def check(line):
    with lock:
        counter.value += 1
    if counter.value == 5:
        with lock:
            counter.value -= 5
        print('Counter Reached 5 in process ', mp.current_process() )
        return 1
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        return 0

pool = Pool(processes=4)
results = pool.map(check, range(15))
print(results)
```

Which gives (note that the process that gets to '5' first is random)..

```
Counter Reached 5 in process  <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
Counter Reached 5 in process  <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
Counter Reached 5 in process  <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

The `Lock()` will prevent potential race issues when modifying the `Value`.  If you remove the `with lock:` lines and run the above code a bunch of times, you'll see it intermittently print only twice because of the race condition.  There is a nice discussion of `Lock` [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing).